# I am trying to retrieve a List of Category and Comments By Using the Sprint Boot where Comment ID is Repeating for every Object

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, rest, jpa

Here is the Background information of my Restful API. I am trying to create Many to One Relation between Comments and Category Where Many Comments belong to One Category. If I am trying to call the Get All Categories -> I am getting the correct response. Also, If I am trying to call the Comments API where I am passing the CategoryID as a Path Variable I am able to retrive the correct response as well. However, When I am trying to consolidate the API, it is repeating the comments even though they are not belong to category one For instance.

**Category Entity**

package com.mshakir.restfulwebservice.dto.entity;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
@Entity 
@Table(name = "categories") 
`
public class Category {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "category_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "category_generator", sequenceName = "category_sequence", initialValue = 20000, allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "category_id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "category_name", nullable = false, length = 32)
private String categoryName;

@Column(name = "category_desc", nullable = false, length = 64)
private String categoryDescription;

@Column(name = "is_published", nullable = false, length = 32)
private boolean isPublished = true;

@Transient
private String publishedMessage;

private String isActive;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCategoryName() {
    return categoryName;
}

public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
}

public String getCategoryDescription() {
    return categoryDescription;
}

public void setCategoryDescription(String categoryDescription) {
    this.categoryDescription = categoryDescription;
}

public boolean getIsPublished() {
    return isPublished;
}

public void setIsPublished(boolean isPublished) {
    this.isPublished = isPublished;
}

public String getPublishedMessage() {
    String message = "";
    if (isPublished) {
        message = "Category Id has been published to the Website";
    } else {
        message = "Category Id has not been published to the Website";
    }
    return message;
}

public String getIsActive() {
    return isActive;
}

public void setIsActive(String isActive) {
    this.isActive = isActive;
}

public void setPublishedMessage(String publishedMessage) {
    this.publishedMessage = publishedMessage;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Category [id=" + id + ", categoryName=" + categoryName + ", categoryDescription=" + categoryDescription
            + " , isActive=" + isActive + "]";
}

}`
```

**Comment Entity**
package com.mshakir.restfulwebservice.dto.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity; 
import javax.persistence.FetchType; 
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue; 
import javax.persistence.GenerationType; 
import javax.persistence.Id; 
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn; 
import javax.persistence.Lob; 
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne; 
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator; 
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

`@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "comment_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "comment_generator", sequenceName = "comment_sequence", initialValue = 15001, allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "comment_id")
private Long id;

@Lob
@Column(name = "comment_content")
private String content;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private Category category;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Comment [id=" + id + ", content=" + content + ", category=" + category + "]";
}
```

}`

**Category Controller with Implement Service**
`
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/categories")
public class CategoryController {
public static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CategoryController.class);

```
@Autowired
CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

@Autowired
CommentRepository commentRepository;

private final CategoryServiceImpl categoryServiceImpl;

@Autowired
public CategoryController(CategoryServiceImpl categoryServiceImpl) {
    this.categoryServiceImpl = categoryServiceImpl;
}

@PostMapping("/create-new-category")
public ResponseEntity<Category> createCategoryRecord(@RequestBody Category category) throws Exception {
    log.info("Category Controller: createCategoryRecord()");
    Category createNewCategory = categoryServiceImpl.createNewCategory(category);
    HttpStatus statusCreated201 = HttpStatus.CREATED;
    return new ResponseEntity<Category>(createNewCategory, statusCreated201);
}
}`
```

**Implement Service Method For this Post Category**
`
@Service
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {

```
private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

@Autowired
public CategoryServiceImpl(CategoryRepository categoryRepository) {
    this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
}

@Override
public Category createNewCategory(Category category) {
    String categoryName = category.getCategoryName();
    Optional<Category> findByCategoryName = categoryRepository.findByCategoryName(categoryName);
    if (findByCategoryName.isPresent()) {
        throw new InvalidDataException("Category already exists in the Database");
    }
    Category newCategory = categoryRepository.save(category);
    return newCategory;
}
}`
```

**Show All Categories**
`
@GetMapping("/show-all-categories") 
public ResponseEntity<List>
showAllCategoriesAll(@RequestParam(required = false) String categoryName) { 
List listOfCategories = new ArrayList();
if (Utils.isEmptyString(categoryName)) {
categoryRepository.findAll().forEach(category -> {
listOfCategories.add(category);
});

```
    }
    else {
        List<Category> findByCategoryNameContaining = categoryRepository.findByCategoryNameContaining(categoryName);
        findByCategoryNameContaining.forEach(category -> listOfCategories.add(category));
    }
    
    if (listOfCategories.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Category>>(listOfCategories, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
                    
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Category>>(listOfCategories, HttpStatus.OK);
}`
```

**Get List of Comments Based on Category ID** 
`
@GetMapping("/categories/{categoryId}/comments") 
public ResponseEntity<List> 
getAllCommentsByTutorialId(@PathVariable(value = "categoryId") Long categoryId) {
if (!categoryRepository.existsById(categoryId)) {
throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Not found Tutorial with id = " + categoryId);
}

```
    List<Comment> comments = commentRepository.findByCategoryId(categoryId);
    
    List<Comment> findAll = commentRepository.findAll();
    for (Comment comment: findAll) {
        System.out.println(comment.getCategory().getCategoryName());
        System.out.println(comment.getCategory().getCategoryDescription());
    }
    System.out.println(findAll);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(comments, HttpStatus.OK);
  }`
```

**Consolidated API**
`
@RestController 
@RequestMapping("/list-of-categories") 
public class ListOfCategory {

```
@Autowired
CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

@Autowired
CommentRepository commentRepository;

@GetMapping("/show-all")
public ResponseEntity<List<CategoryCommentResponse>> showAll() {
    List<CommentInfo> listOfComments = new ArrayList<CommentInfo>();
    List<CategoryCommentResponse> listofAll = new ArrayList<CategoryCommentResponse>();
    List<Category> categoryList = categoryRepository.findAll();
    System.out.println(categoryList);
    for (Category category : categoryList) {
        CategoryCommentResponse response = new CategoryCommentResponse();
        Long categoryId = category.getId();
        response.setCategoryId(categoryId);
        response.setCategoryDescription(category.getCategoryDescription());
        response.setCategoryName(category.getCategoryName());
        List<Comment> listOfCommentsByCategoryId = commentRepository.findByCategoryId(categoryId);
        
        for (Comment comment : listOfCommentsByCategoryId) {
            CommentInfo commentInfo = new CommentInfo();
            Long commentId = comment.getId();
            commentInfo.setId(commentId);
            commentInfo.setContent(comment.getContent());
            System.out.println(commentInfo);
            listOfComments.add(commentInfo);
            response.setComments(listOfComments);
        }
        listofAll.add(response);
    }
    
    return new ResponseEntity<List<CategoryCommentResponse>>(listofAll, HttpStatus.OK);

}
}`
```

Please find attached Screenshot to review as well. Thank you

[ConsolidatedAPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkt3C.png)

[List Of Categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rNgC.png)

[List Of Comments based on Category Id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5iPp.png)

Comment: Instead of posting as image you can paste the code block. It will be useful for us to help.

Comment: Is this a problem with your findAll method do you think, or is the data in the database incorrect (or unexpected)? I don't think anyone can help unless you show the code for the post comments API - what exactly you are doing and how it works, as well as the model used. Note that your show-all is showing the same category twice. Do you really want duplicate categories returned when they have multiple comments or can it be assumed your query isn't optimal?

Comment: @Rajeshkumar I have updated thread by adding all the code

Comment: @Chris Please review the new Updated thread with updated Screen shot

Comment: I am able to get list of categories. I am able to get list of comments based on Category Id
When I am trying to combine both of these endpoints in one consolidated API that's where it is keep repeating the ID's not certain what is going on

Comment: For Reference This is online tutorial I am following 
`https://www.bezkoder.com/jpa-one-to-many/`

It does not have a consolidated API which I wrote it, yet I am having a minor issue. Hoping someone here pinpoint the issue.

Comment: The original question showed 'show-all' returning two instances of category with ID 20001 - is that not the case? If it is returning 20000 and 20001 category instances correctly, verify that your method is actually running "commentRepository.findByCategoryId(categoryId)" on those two ID values, and what it is returning. And also that you don't have a cut and paste or other code error that might cause you to reuse the same resulting list or some find-all type call under the covers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is a logic flaw in your showAll method. You instantiate and build a single listOfComments List and populate it with comments as you process categories, and use this same list for all categories. As it runs, the list will contain all comments from them all.

Each Category needs its own independent list:

```
public ResponseEntity<List<CategoryCommentResponse>> showAll() {
  ..
    List<Comment> listOfCommentsByCategoryId =commentRepository.findByCategoryId(categoryId);
    List<CommentInfo> listOfCommentInfos = new ArrayList<CommentInfo>();
        
    for (Comment comment : listOfCommentsByCategoryId) {
      CommentInfo commentInfo = new CommentInfo();
      commentInfo.setId(comment.getId());
      commentInfo.setContent(comment.getContent());
      System.out.println(commentInfo);
      listOfCommentInfos.add(commentInfo);
      response.setComments(listOfCommentInfos);
    }
    listofAll.add(response);
  }
    
  return new ResponseEntity<List<CategoryCommentResponse>>(listofAll, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. It worked. I appreciated. I knew it was a minor glitch I am having.